# Laravel foreign key doesn't output expected result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I'm developing a Laravel 9 web app and there I have two tables (`users` and `feedbacks`) which connects using a foreign key named `username`. One single user can have many feedbacks. As I know if I get details of a a user those data contains the relevant feedbacks too. My issue is that the user data is fetched properly but it comes with all feedbacks and not the feedbacks which connect to that specific user. The Laravel executes a query like this.

```sql
select * from `feedback` where `feedback`.`username` = 0 and `feedback`.`username` is not null
```

As I understand 0 should be replaced by the user's username. What is the issue here?

`Feedback` Model-

```php
class Feedback extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    //One single user can have many feedbacks.
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

`User` model-

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'gender',
        'email',
        'password',
        'is_admin',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'is_admin',
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'username';

    public function feedbacks() {
        return $this->hasMany(Feedback::class, 'username');
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

`create_users_table` migration-

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('userId');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

`create_feedback_table` migration-

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('feedback', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('feedbackId');
            $table->text('feedback');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('username')
                ->references('username')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

`FeedbackController` to get the data,

```php
class FeedbackController extends Controller
{
    public function giveFeedback($username)
    {
        $userData = User::find($username);

        dd($userData->feedbacks);

        return view('feedback.givefeedback', compact('userData'));
    }
}
```

`users` table-
[image: users table]

`feedback` table-
[image: feedback table]

This is the output on the blade, As you can see it outputs all the feedback even though I only requested the feedbacks of `nerigupex` using routes.
[image: screenshot of the blade file]

Please request if you need more code to resolve this issue, I will update the question accordingly. TIA.

Comment: what do you need as output? Elaborate more on this please

Comment: Typo(should be username i think) but it's not solution: public function feedbacks() {
        return $this->hasMany(Feedback::class, 'usernadme');
    }

Comment: @MartinAmu corrected. I changed that just for testings.

Comment: @pasindu Foreign key should be `user_id`. It is a **unsignedBigInteger** not **string**

Comment: @AbdullaNilam my route is this `Route::get('/{username}', [FeedbackController::class, 'giveFeedback']);` so when I give the username as a URL parameter it should show the relevant user details and the feedbacks they received. So if you notice in the last screenshot, the URL parameter I gave was `nerigupex`, but as you can see it outputs all the feedbacks which include user `gapunix` feedbacks as well. I only need the feedbacks of `nerigupex`.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I need to use `username` as the foreign key. because URL parameter will be the username. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @pasindu it is very important that you read the documentation. There is a specific section on the documentation talking about [Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), and you are following none of it, hence you will have lot of issues

Answer (score 1):

Do like this (Only addressing Dataload issue)

### 1. Refator the Migration

**User Migration**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id'); # change your current primary key to this

    .... rest of the code
}
```

**Feedback Migration**

```
Schema::create('feedback', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id'); # change your current primary key to this
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

    .... rest of the code
}
```

### 2. Refator the Model

```
//protected $primaryKey = 'username'; --> remove this

public function feedbacks() {
    return $this->hasMany(Feedback::class);
}
```

### 3. In Feedback Controller

```
class FeedbackController extends Controller
{
    public function giveFeedback($username)
    {
        $userData = User::with('feedbacks')->where('username', $username)->get();

        dd($userData->feedbacks);

        return view('feedback.givefeedback', compact('userData'));
    }
}
```